# 404 error custom post type rest api

Tags: ajax, rest-api

I'm having trouble to get some custom post type using the REST API.
I get a 404 message but all the settings are right. Is there a fix?

```
<div class="row services-content">
<?php $services = new WP_Query( ['post_type' => 'servizi'] ); ?>
<?php if( wp_is_mobile() ): ?>
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="padding:0;">
    <div class="swiper-container services-carousel">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <?php if( $services->have_posts() ): while( $services->have_posts() ): $services->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url('<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');">
        <h4 class="service-slide-name"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      </div>
      <!-- Pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      <!-- Arrows -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php else: ?>
<?php if( $services->have_posts() ): while( $services->have_posts() ): $services->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="d-sm-none d-md-block col-md-3 col-lg-3 service-col">
    <img class="rounded-circle service-icon hide" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" width="60">
    <a class="open-modal" href="#modal-content" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-toggle="modal" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="content"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.open-modal', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      $.getJSON('wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'+id , function(data){
        console.log(data);

      });
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

The post type is set to public and has the show in rest attribubte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare that your CPT supports REST via `show_in_rest` when registering it, then use the REST API endpoint for that post type.

For example, I have a CPT on my own site for talks named `tomjn_talks`, and it has an endpoint at `/wp/v2/tomjn_talks`

Comment: yeah, that's truth. I've solved